# Racket: number of arguments

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to implement a decision tree in Racket manually to see how it works. 
I have this structure:

```
(define-struct node
  (list : childs
        class attribute type ))
```

and my function:

```
(define tree-1 
  (node '((node null 'round 'yes null) (node null 'square 'yes null)) 'shape null null))
```

Basically I want a tree with 3 nodes as follow:

```
;;    shape
;;     / \
;; round square
   (yes)  (no)
```

"Yes" and "no" are representing the classes for each atribute.

I get the following error:
**node: expects 6 arguments, given 4: '((node null 'round 'yes null) (node null 'square 'yes null)) 'shape '() '()** but my node should take 4 arguments so i do not see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `node` seems kind of odd:

```
(define-struct node
  (list : childs
        class attribute type ))
```

That defines a struct with 6 members: `list`, `:`, `childs`, `class`, `attribute`, and `type`.

That defines a `node` constructor that expects those 6 arguments, but you call the constructor with only 4 arguments:

```
(node '((node null 'round 'yes null) (node null 'square 'yes null))
      'shape null null))
```

I'm guessing you meant those to be the `childs`, `class`, `attribute`, and `type`.

When you take "`list :`" out of the struct definition, the next problem you'll run into is that you probably meant to be passing a list of two `node`s as that first argument. Instead you're passing a list of two lists, each list containing the symbols `node`, and `null`, followed by a list `(quote round)` or `(quote square)`, etc. All because of your use of the quote (`'`) operator instead of quasiquote. Try this:

```
(node `(,(node null 'round 'yes null) ,(node null 'square 'yes null))
      'shape null null))
```